# How to solve Build failed in react native?

Tags: react-native

[here is my problem or error I'm facing please click here to see...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq2Iq.png)

**Here is my node error in metro bundler..**

```
                    #######
               ################
            #########     #########
        #########             ##########
    #########        ######        #########
   ##########################################
  #####      #####################       #####
  #####          ##############          #####
  #####    ###       ######       ###    #####
  #####    #######            #######    #####
  #####    ###########    ###########    #####
  #####    ##########################    #####
  #####    ##########################    #####
  #####      ######################     ######
   ######        #############        #######
     #########        ####       #########
          #########          #########
              ######### #########
                   #########


                Welcome to Metro!
          Fast - Scalable - Integrated
```

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
at stableHash (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
at Object.getCacheKey (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:593:7)
at getTransformCacheKey (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
at new Transformer (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:48:9)
at D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:22:29 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

*This is an error I'm getting ...*

> PS D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native> npm run android

> eMembershipCard@0.0.4 android
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 3139 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'eMembershipCard'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7: 1.7.20.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/ 1.7.20/kotlin-stdlib-jre7- 1.7.20.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/ 1.7.20/kotlin-stdlib-jre7- 1.7.20.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'eMembershipCard'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7: 1.7.20.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/ 1.7.20/kotlin-stdlib-jre7- 1.7.20.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/ 1.7.20/kotlin-stdlib-jre7- 1.7.20.pom
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

```
at makeError (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)   
at D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
PS D:\EMproject\eMembership-React-Native>

**Here is my package.json file...**

```
{
  "name": "eMembershipCard",
  "version": "0.0.4",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android_emembershipcard": "react-native run-android --variant=emembershipcardDebug  --appIdSuffix = 'membershipdemo' ",
    "android_omaha": "react-native run-android --variant=omahaDebug  --appIdSuffix = 'ocm' ",
    "android_magichouse": "react-native run-android --variant=magichouseDebug  --appIdSuffix = 'magichouse' ",
    "ios_emembershipcard": "react-native run-ios --scheme eMembershipCard --configuration eMembershipCard",
    "ios_omaha": "react-native run-ios --scheme omaha --configuration omaha",
    "ios_magichouse": "react-native run-ios --scheme magichouse --configuration magichouse",
    "emembership-build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleemembershipcardRelease",
    "emembership-build-debug": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleemembershipcardDebug",
    "omaha-build-debug": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleomahaDebug",
    "magichouse-build-debug": "cd android && ./gradlew assemblemagichouseDebug",
    "emembership-build-debug-bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleemembershipcardDebug",
    "omaha-build-debug-bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundleomahaDebug",
    "magichouse-build-debug-bundle": "cd android && ./gradlew bundlemagichouseDebug"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.12.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.2.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "android": "^0.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "linkify-html": "^3.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.11",
    "react-native-dots-pagination": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gradient-buttons": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-marquee": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-share": "^7.3.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.14.10",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "react-native-wallet": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

What I have tried...

1. I think the commands which is necessary to solve the error I have tried ...
2. And also I have set the environment setup very properly as the react native setup docs says ...
3. I have updated gradle version , kotlin version, react native version , npm version , node version etc...
4. I have also updated Firebase app , Firebase message and Firebase.. where Firebase app and messages version should be same...
5. I have also set up the SDK TOOLS, Android SDK in Android studio ...
6. I have uninstalled the nodes, vs code and again reinstalled it but again facing the same issue i.e.     Build Failed....

---

**Here is my android/build.gradle ...

`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
        android_plugin_version = '7.3.1'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7: 1.7.20"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Can you kindly add the error message maybe helpful